# Running struts2 framework on ubuntu tomcat7 : failed

Tags: ubuntu, struts2, struts, tomcat7

Been trying to learn how to develop struts 2 web application, I've followed many tutorial, but after added all needed library, configured struts.xml, web.xml, etc, I couldn't run it both in my debug or running server on my machine. after struggling for many2 days, now I found out, when I downloaded some struts2 webapp examples on the struts2 website and tried to deploy struts2-blank on tomcat7 using the same process. This one is also doesn't work. for those who will post some advice to show my web.xml file inside, I guess its not necessary, because, when I was trying to run the same applications under windows machine, they are working very well, thus, I need your advice from someone who had encountered the same problem. thanks in advance.

this is my configuration :

1. ubuntu linux 12.04,32-bit

   - tomcat 7 installed with apt-get also have tried to install tar.gz version
   - java ee IDE eclipse Helios, and Indigo
   - struts 2.3.16 and all dependencies

this is my error message :

FAIL - Application at context path /struts2-blank could not be started

same goes with other examples from struts2 web

Comment: Add the whole console error in the question. It will give some information to analyze it.

Comment: Did you try to deploy war file from the `apps` package.?

Comment: nope, i deployed them at my localhost:8080/manager/html same file with the one that im using on windows tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forget about Tomcat, its time to use Weblogic, way much better than Tomcat. thanks for any attentions